# How to run another USSD command from an already running USSD Menu

Tags: php

I have developed a `USSD` Menu that is running on the smartphone using a USSD shortcode ***5454#**.

When it runs a menu is **displayed** on the phone with **4 options**.

But now I want when a *select option 4 menu*, then I want **another** `USSD` shortcode ***203#** to run which will also display another menu.

How can I go about doing this??

Comment: Improved text formatting and highlighted the problems for better understanding of the question

Comment: well I never worked with USSDs but if you have a function to place a normal call I think it will work for running another USSD also.